# Cannot set the value properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 6 following radio buttons

```
<input type="text" id="status" name="status">

<input type="radio" name="orderReceivingKeysPresent" id="orderReceivingKeysPresent_Y" value="1" onclick="checkKeyAndTitle(this);"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="orderReceivingKeysPresent" id="orderReceivingKeysPresent_N" value="0" onclick="checkKeyAndTitle(this);"> No

<input type="radio" name="orderReceivingTitlePresent" id="orderReceivingTitlePresent_Y" value="1" onclick="checkKeyAndTitle(this);"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="orderReceivingTitlePresent" id="orderReceivingTitlePresent_N" value="0" onclick="checkKeyAndTitle(this);"> No

<input type="radio" name="orderReceivingReturnToOwner" id="orderReceivingReturnToOwner_Y" value="1" onclick="hideAndShowReturnToOwner(this); checkKeyAndTitle(this);"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="orderReceivingReturnToOwner" id="orderReceivingReturnToOwner_N" value="0" onclick="hideAndShowReturnToOwner(this); checkKeyAndTitle(this);" checked="checked"> No
```

No I'm using javascript for assiging values. I've created javascript function but it isn't working properly and I can't figure it out. How to do it?

```
function checkKeyAndTitle(getObj) {
    if(getObj.name == "orderReceivingKeysPresent") {
        if(getObj.value == "1") {
            $("#status").val('Delivered');
        } else {
            $("#status").val('Missing Keys');
        }
    }
    else {
        if(getObj.value == "1") {
            $("#status").val('Delivered');
        } else {
            $("#status").val('Missing Title');
        }
    }
}
```

Now `orderReceivingReturnToOwner` is checked to no by default.
When I click at `orderReceivingKeysPresent` to yes and `orderReceivingTitlePresent` to no then status should be `Missing Title` and when `orderReceivingKeysPresent` no and `orderReceivingTitlePresent` yes status should be `Missing Keys` and when both are yes status should be `Delivered` and also check this one to when `orderReceivingReturnToOwner` yes status should be `Return To Owner`. Help suggest me how to do it.

Comment: where is your `#status` element in html?

Comment: tell me how to do it?

Comment: It is working for me: _http://jsfiddle.net/r78Lrqfs/1/_

Comment: Its not working properly when title is present and keys are not status should be `missing keys` when title is not present and keys are present status should be `missing title` when both are not available status should be `missing keys/title` when return to owner is 1 the status should be `return to owner`.

Comment: So no one gonna help me with my logic for this issue. I want to use javascript function not jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("click", function () {
    var keyRadioVal = $('input:radio[name=orderReceivingKeysPresent]:checked').val();
    var titleRadioVal = $('input:radio[name=orderReceivingTitlePresent]:checked').val();
    var ownerRadioVal = $('input:radio[name=orderReceivingReturnToOwner]:checked').val();

    if (ownerRadioVal == 1) {
        $("#status").val('Return To Owner');
    } else if (keyRadioVal == 1 && titleRadioVal == 0 && ownerRadioVal == 0) {
        $("#status").val('Missing Title');
    } else if (titleRadioVal == 1 && keyRadioVal == 0 && ownerRadioVal == 0) {
        $("#status").val('Missing Keys');
    } else if (titleRadioVal == 1 && keyRadioVal == 1 && ownerRadioVal == 0) {
        $("#status").val('Delivered ');
    } else {
        $("#status").val('Missing Keys');
    }
});
```

what i had done is getting value of each radio button which is selected on selection change of every single radio button and check all 3 case.

rest  in all case Missing key will be shown that you can accordingly.